# how to display an entity using FreeMarker?

Tags: html, spring-boot, freemarker

I have the entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="fights")
public class Fight {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long fightid;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "fight", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Sportsman> sportsmans;

private Long identifWin;

private Long identifEvent;
/* getters and setters */
}
```

and Controller

```
@GetMapping("/fights")
public String getAllFights(Model model) {
    List fights = fightServise.getAllFight();
    model.addAttribute("fights", fights);
    return "fights";
}
```

I don't know how to display this Entity using FreeMarker.
this code displays something incomprehensible:

```
<form method="get" action="/fights">
<#list fights as fight>
    ${fight}
<#else>
    No fight
</#list>
```

if I access individual fields, I get an exception.

> reeMarker template error (DEBUG mode; use RETHROW in production!): The following has evaluated to null or missing: ==> fight.fightid [in template "fights.ftl" at line 3, column 11]

Values exist in the database
UPDATE
the second entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sportsmans")
public class Sportsman {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

private String firstName;

private String lastName;

private String alias;

private int growth;

private int weight;

private int lengthOfHands;

private int countOfLose;

private int countOfWin;

private int countOfDraw;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="fightid")
private Fight fight;
/* getters and setters */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="get" action="/fights">
<#list fights as fight>
    <#list fight.getSportsmans() as b>
        ${b.getFirstName()}
    </#list>
<#else>
    No fight
</#list>
```

Comment: Although this code might (or might not) solve the problem, a good answer should explain what the code does and how it solves the problem.

Comment: Note that instead of `fight.getSportsmans()` you can write `fight.sportsmans`, and instead of `b.getFirstName()` you can write `b.firstName`.